# How to delete a specific element from a dynamic array?

Tags: c, typedef, dynamic-arrays

I am currently trying to make it so that when the user gives a student ID to my program it will compare it with all the other ID's and if it exists in the array then it will delete it using realloc.

Here are some parts of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct student {
    int id;
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    int semester;
    float grade;
} student;

int
main()
{
    int x,
     std,
     i,
     k,
     size1,
     size2;

    x = 0;
    int car = 0;
    int flag = 1;
    struct student *ptr = NULL;

    while (x != 8) {
        printf("\n"
            "1. Initialize student list\n"
            "2. Add a student record\n"
            "3. Delete a student record\n"
            "4. Display a student record by student surname\n"
            "5. Display students passed\n"
            "6. Display students failed\n"
            "7. Display all student records\n"
            "8. Exit");
        printf("\nYour choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);

        if (x == 1) {
            printf("How many new students? ");
            scanf("%d", &std);
            ptr = (student *) malloc(std * sizeof(student));
            size1 = std;
            for (i = 0; i < std; i++) {
                printf("Enter detail of student #%d\n", (i + 1));
                ptr[i].id = i + 1;
                printf("Enter first name: ");
                scanf("%s", ptr[i].name);
                printf("Enter last name: ");
                scanf("%s", ptr[i].surname);
                printf("Enter semester: ");
                scanf("%d", &ptr[i].semester);
                printf("Enter grade: ");
                scanf("%f", &ptr[i].grade);
            }
        }

        else if (x == 3) {
            printf("Give the ID you wish to delete:\n");
            scanf("%d", &k);
            for (i = 0; i < std; i++) {
                if (k == ptr[i].id) {
                    std = std - 1;
                    size2 = std;
                    ptr[i] = ptr[i + 1];
                    memmove(ptr,ptr + (size1 - size2),size2 * sizeof(student));
                    ptr = realloc(ptr, std * sizeof(student));
                }
            }
        }

        else if (x == 7) {
            for (i = 0; i < std; i++) {
                printf("%d ", ptr[i].id);
                printf("%s ", ptr[i].name);
                printf("%s ", ptr[i].surname);
                printf("%d ", ptr[i].semester);
                printf("%f ", ptr[i].grade);
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried adding another for loop in the `if(x==3)` under the `if (k==ptr[i].id)` to move everything but when it tries to print it either gives me the next students information 2 times or it just prints some random numbers and letters which doesn't help. I have also tried to change `std`. Sometimes upping it by 1 other times lowering it by 1. It still didn't give me the results I expected. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something pretty obvious but it's been a few hours and I still haven't found a way to make it work.

What I want from it is to read the ID. Compare it with `ptr[i].id` to see if it exists and if it does exist then I simply want to delete it and everything that comes with it. Basically overwrite `ptr[i]`(which has the id I want to delete) with the next one which would be `ptr[i+1]`

Comment: `realloc` does not delete anything, it just reallocates.  If you want to do random deletions, an array is the wrong data structure.

Comment: Your `memmove` seems very wrong.  You don't want to copy anything to the beginning of the array, you just want to move everything in the tail up 1 position.  I would expect to see `memmove(ptr + x, ptr + x + 1, ...)` where x is the number of entries that are kept.

Comment: I didn't read your code, but instead of moving things around, you could mark that element as ```AVAILABLE``` (where ```AVAILABLE``` is some macro with a unique value), and then check for an available spot when adding another element. Or perhaps use a linked list?

Comment: Note: `scanf("%s", ptr[i].name); ... scanf("%s", ptr[i].surname);` will not work to scan in names that have spaces in the first or last names.